# How do I create and run an executable jar with maven that has external dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, executable-jar

I have a jar plugin but it's not running because it isn't including the external dependencies in the jar. I can't seem to figure out how to include these dependencies, I seem to be finding a bunch of different solutions that conflict with each other for some reason. I ideally would like it to run on systems without the need for any special maven commands.

Comment: you mean you want to export your plugin with all the jars packaged along with it? Can http://stackoverflow.com/q/574594/2231632 help?

Comment: I basically mean I want my java application to be command line executable. I don't want the user of my executable jar to have to have maven to run it. So ideally I would like a different solution than the one you linked.

Comment: You could use maven assembly plugin to create a jar with dependencies  [jar-with-dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

create maven pom.xml with

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

By default it should not pack into your jar all dependent libraries.

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>install</phase>
       <goals>
        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
       </goals>
     <configuration>
       <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
     </configuration>
 </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: If you dont have a manifest in your jar invoking java -jar will not work.

Use this command if you dont have a manifest:"java -cp foo.jar full.package.name.ClassName" or this is common command "java -jar <jar-file-name>.jar" Now can you vote up my answer please?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is to build an über-jar. The Maven Shade plugin can do that - http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/. It even allows for renaming of classes.